# .NET multi layer request variable

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, custom-headers

I am a .NET newbie and finding it difficult to come up with a good way to do the following.
I have a requirement where in ASP.NET I receive a custom HTTP header (that is unique per request). I want to print this variable in the logs across various layers that handle this request (controller, logic layer etc).

I initially thought of a IHttpModule that will process the headers and retrieve this custom header and store it in a ThreadLocal storage. The Logging framework can read from this and print it as part of the message.

But ran into issues, because the logic layer processing happens on a different thread and hence the system loses context of this request.

I am looking for a non-intrusive way to do this, that can happen transparently without changing the core code of the system. This way I can turn on or off the feature without any change in the code.

Is there any framework level support for something like this or any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Items` and an action filter.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the suggestion. Can you please elaborate more on this? The Logging framework and the Logic layer are not HttpContext aware. On the Controller I can place the request in HttpContext.Items but context switches to Logic layer, which is a different thread, this context is not valid anymore correct?